# Error: ENOENT, no such file or directory '/var/www/html/views while publishing app on ubuntu

Tags: node.js, express, mean-stack

My nodejs application folder structure is like below.

Index.html file is inside the views folder and public folder contains the partials pages.

Below is a small snippet from index.html and it works fine while node runs locally on machine.

```
<section id="sidebar"  ng-controller="menuController" ng-init="init()">
    <% include ..\public\partials\_menubar.html %>
</section>
```

[image]

But when I run the code on server, it gives me error.

```
Error: ENOENT, no such file or directory        
'/var/www/html/views/..\public\partials\_menubar.html'
 at Object.fs.openSync (fs.js:432:18)
 at Object.fs.readFileSync (fs.js:286:15)
 at includeSource (/var/www/html/node_modules/ejs/lib/ejs.js:194:17)
 at /var/www/html/node_modules/ejs/lib/ejs.js:528:26
 at Array.forEach (native)
 at Object.Template.generateSource (/var/www/html/node_modules/ejs/lib/ejs.js:505:15)
 at Object.Template.compile (/var/www/html/node_modules/ejs/lib/ejs.js:427:12)
 at Object.compile (/var/www/html/node_modules/ejs/lib/ejs.js:288:16)
 at handleCache (/var/www/html/node_modules/ejs/lib/ejs.js:147:16)
 at View.exports.renderFile [as engine]     (/var/www/html/node_modules/ejs/lib/ejs.js:350:14)
```

I have tried using below code but no success.

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
```

Comment: linux uses `/` as directory separator. You are using windows' `\\`

Comment: You are awesome @baao Please write the answer i will accept

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Linux uses `/` as directory separator so the file's can't be found as you are using windows' `\` separator.

Also note that, other than windows, linux is case sensitive so you need to make sure to have the correct case in your file/directory names.